# How to update a working copy to HEAD and write all the commit logs to an output file with Tortoise SVN

Tags: batch-file, tortoisesvn

Our project is using Tortoise SVN as version control. How can I write a batch script to auto update certain working copy and write the commit notes of the updated revisions between builds (of any format, XML, text, JSON, etc.)?

For example, the current working copy is at rev. 150 and the head rev is 200, the script will have to update it to rev 200 and the log file must show all commit notes from rev. 151 to 200.

Currently, I'm writing it like this:

`call svn update %REPO%>%LOGFILE%`

Somehow the script still fails to update and the log file only shows:

> Updating 'Repo':
> At revision HEAD.

While the working copy doesn't update and no commit log were inserted.

Comment: @Álvaro González Yeah, thanks for the correction. English isn't my first language and in our daily work we always refer to working copy as either "trunk" or "repo" so it kind of imprinted. It's lucky that people can still understand it.

Comment: I'm not proficient with CMD scripting (who is?) but I believe `call` is used to invoke other batch scripts. Since you need to invoke a regular program (which, by the way, is an optional component in TortoiseSVN installer but not really part of it) I don't think you need it, and it might be causing other issues.